# Redirecting to another URL without losing the values in header

Tags: c#, javascript, forms, redirect, header

I just want to ask if it is possible to redirect to another URL without losing the values in header. The values in header are used for validation in Single Sign On function.

I can't use query strings for security purposes.

Thanks in advance!
:)

Comment: Is the redirect happening in C#? I don't know enough C# to give you a full answer, but generally your script just needs to [get all the request headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [begin a redirect response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and [append the headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) back to the response.